# How can I remove a file before appRun

Tags: gradle, gretty

I need to delete `web.xml` from `build/inplaceWebapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` just after the `prepareInplaceApp` task when running appRun.  I tried :

```
prepareInplaceWebApp {
    doLast {
        println "aaaaa"  // not sure what to put here either
    }
}
```

But that gave me an `error` :

> Could not find method prepareInplaceWebApp() for arguments...

The `web.xml` I have is tomcat specific and causes problems with appRun.  appRun runs fine without any `web.xml` file.

Thanks!

Blake McBride

Comment: Is it `prepareInplaceApp` or `prepareInplaceWebApp`? Once you know the exact task name, you can add a `doLast { }` action like you are, and just do `file("$buildDir/inplaceWebapp/WEB-INF/web.xml").delete()`

Comment: I used the "-i" option to determine the task name.  Here is a cut-and-paste:  `Task :prepareInplaceWebApp`  Here is the full error message I get:  `Could not find method prepareInplaceWebApp() for arguments [build_bmhdzo8wm3sinyxrzrqlhkbyg$_run_closure4@1a2dcc95] on root project 'Kiss' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: Try `tasks.getByName('prepareInplaceWebApp') { doLast { } }`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The error response is `Task with name 'prepareInplaceWebApp' not found in root project 'Kiss'.`

Answer (score 0):

The task `prepareInplaceWebApp` of the Gretty plugin is added after the project is evaluated. You can see this in the [GrettyPlugin.groovy](https://github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty/blob/master/libs/gretty/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/GrettyPlugin.groovy) file where in line 
[287](https://github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty/blob/master/libs/gretty/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/GrettyPlugin.groovy#L287) the task is created, and attached to the project in line [816](https://github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty/blob/master/libs/gretty/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/GrettyPlugin.groovy#L816).

In order to use `prepareInplaceWebApp` in your build.gradle file you have to wrap your code in a `afterEvaluate` closure since the task is not available during configuration time. In example:

```
afterEvaluate {
    prepareInplaceWebApp {
        doLast {
            println "hello world"
        }
    }
}
```